# React native image upload with presigned url using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

```
const handleUpload = () => {
        let data = {
            "fileDetails": [
                {
                    "extension": `${image[0].uri.substr(image[0].uri.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)}`,
                    "fileType": `image/${image[0].uri.substr(image[0].uri.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)}`
                }
            ]
        }
        let img = {
            uri:  image[0].uri, // image uri
            name: "profile",
            type: "image/jpg"
        }
        axios.post('/client/update/image', data, {headers}) // getting presigned urls
        .then(resp => {
            let header = {
                'Content-Type': "image/jpg"
            }
            axios.put(resp.data.presignedUrls[0].url, img, {headers:header})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res, 'response from aws')
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

I am uploading image uri to the presigned url which I got. But when I open the image it displays the small grey colored box.

But It works well with xmlhttp request

```
            // xhr.open('PUT', resp.data.presignedUrls[0].url);
            // xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg';
            // xhr.send({uri: image[0].uri, type: 'image/jpg', name: 'image/jpg'});
```

Why it doesn't work with axios in a way it works with xmlhttp.

Comment: 'Content-Type': image/jpg` your syntax is incorrect. Image/jpg is not in quotes

Comment: actually that was a mistake i'll edit  this now

Comment: Both image/jpg in  type: image/jpg and 'Content-Type': image/jpg need to be in quotes